# Declare vs Proc parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a stored procedure, is setting something a parameter and declaring something different?

For example: if I needed to make something a parameter which would be right or wrong?

```
Alter Prodedure dbo.users_checkin 
    @userid INT
AS
Begin
```

OR

```
Alter Proc
Begin
    Declare @userid INT
    Declare @date1 DATE
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is completely situational...  You can pass in values to the proc with parameters, but values that are defined in the body of the proc are essentially constant.  It depends on your needs, and they’re by no means mutually exclusive.

Comment: The first defines an argument to the procedure.  The second defines two local variables.  You use the version that is appropriate for what you want -- an argument and/or local variables.

Comment: Do you have experience with other programming languages? If you have experience using any procedural languages, have you ever been confused over whether you should make something a parameter/argument versus making it a local variable?